# Merge downloaded mbtiles

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, merge, mbtiles

I would like to download the data of the whole world (or at least a continent) as mbtiles from the 2nd zoom level to the 12th zoom level using OSM or ESRI Topo Map and use it offline. But I can only do this for a certain size area and I can not merge mbtiles.

How can I merge all these mbtiles?